# Retonar parte de uma string no return da função

Tags: c

Estou tentando achar uma string, e depois percorrer alguns caracteres para ter a informação desejada. Consigo fazer isso, porém, ao invés de apresentar em tela eu gostaria de atribuir a outra variável, para que estes dados coletados após a string encontrada seja o return da minha função.

```
int RetornaString(char *pString1, char *pString2)
{

    char *aux;

    aux = strstr(*pString1,*pString2);

    if (aux != NULL)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 8; i < 24; i++)
            printf("%c",*(aux + i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Desde já, agradeço o tempo dispensado por cada um de vocês, com a minha dúvida!

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Pode mudar o tipo da função para:

```
char* RetornaString(char *pString1, char *pString2)
```

Assim, pode devolver uma parte de uma string qualquer, por exemplo:

```
char* RetornaString(char *pString1, char *pString2) {

    const char string1[20] = "exemplo_palavra";
    const char palavra[10] = "palavra"; 
    char *aux;
    char *retorno;

    aux = strstr(haystack, needle);
    retorno=malloc(sizeof(aux));
    strcpy(retorno,aux);
    return retorno;
 }
```

Ao utilizar memoria dinamica com o malloc garante que o conteudo da string retorno não será perdido quando a função terminar! (Não se esqueça de usar o free para libertar essa mesma memória quando não precisar mais dela!

Comment: Legal ficou muito bom, mas eu ainda preciso de um "for", porquê? Porque, eu quero pegar uma informação que é variável, e sempre vem após a palavra "dados", p.e. Digamos que minha string contenha "dados:HS73NSS9374N7ALW823", Então, estou tentandoi desenvolver uma função que identifique a palavra "dados" percorra 6 bytes e capture 19 bytes a seguir "HS73NSS9374N7ALW823".

Comment: O código que eu postei é um pouco mais genérico, mas deve fazer o que precisa

Answer (score 0):

> eu quero pegar uma informação que é variável, e sempre vem após a palavra "dados", p.e. Digamos que minha string contenha "dados:HS73NSS9374N7ALW823", Então, estou tentando desenvolver uma função que identifique a palavra "dados" percorra 6 bytes e capture 19 bytes a seguir "HS73NSS9374N7ALW823"

Há uma certa ambiguidade na sua questão. Você diz que está procurando `"dados"` mas parece que está procurando `"dados:"` e diz que quer percorrer 6 bytes mas aparentemente quer extrair os dados imediatamente a partir da string que está buscando, que NESSE caso tem 6 bytes se ela for `"dados:"` e não `"dados"` como disse.

Mas o seu exemplo ajudou bem. Ou eu não entendi nada :) nem assim.

Imagine uma função assim:

```
    char* filtro19(
    const char*     origem,
    const char*     prefixo,
    const size_t    deslocamento,
    const size_t    comprimento);
```

Onde

- `origem` é a string inicial,`"dados:HS73NSS9374N7ALW823"` no seu exemplo
- `prefixo` é, quem diria, o prefixo, tipo `"dados:"` no seu exemplo
- `deslocamento` é o deslocamento em bytes a partir de onde vai começar a copiar, 0 no seu exemplo
- `comprimento` é o total de bytes que quer extrair, 19 no seu exemplo

O retorno é um ponteiro para uma string, alocada dinamicamente e que deve ser alvo de um `free()` em algum lugar por sua conta. Claro, retorna `NULL` se não achar os dados a extrair.

Escrevi um exemplo. Não testei além do que vou te mostrar abaixo.

Procurei não chamar nenhuma outra função, exceto `malloc()` e `memcpy()` ao final. Daria para evitar `memcpy()`, mas teria que copiar mesmo e como não dá pra saber se tem todos os bytes a extrair até achar o fim da entrada assim deve ser mais rápido.

Note que precisa testar se de fato tem dados suficientes a extrair antes de terminar a string de entrada, e precisa terminar a string de saída ao final.

Eis a função:

```
    char* filtro19(
    const char*     origem,
    const char*     prefixo,
    const size_t    deslocamento,
    const size_t    comprimento)
{
    size_t    ixIn = 0;
    size_t    ix = 0; // para o deslocamento
    char      st = 0;
    const char* alvo = prefixo;
    char* saida = NULL;
    // vai ate o fim da string de origem
    while (*origem != 0)
    {
        switch (st)
        {

        case 0: // buscando inicio do prefixo
            if (*origem != *prefixo)
            {   // ainda nada
                origem += 1;
                break;
            };  // if()
            origem += 1;
            prefixo += 1;
            st = 1;
            break;

        case 1: // buscando prefixo na string
            if (*prefixo == 0)
            {   // fim do prefixo
                st = 2;
                break;
            };  // if()
            if (*prefixo != *origem)
            {
                st = 0;
                prefixo = alvo; // reinicia prefixo
                break;
            };
            // igual por enquanto
            ixIn += 1; // precisa do tamanho
            origem += 1;
            prefixo += 1;
            break;
        case 2: // andando no intervalo
            if (ix == deslocamento)
            {
                st = 3;
                ix = 0; // agora vai contar a saida
                alvo = origem; // aqui comeca o alvo
                break;
            };
            ix += 1; // anda uma casa
            origem += 1;
            break;
        case 3: // agora aponta para a saida e conta
                // os bytes pedidos
            if (*origem == 0)
            {   // acabou antes: nao tem bytes suficientes
                // depois do prefixo e eventual deslocamento
                return NULL;
            };
            ix += 1;
            if (ix == comprimento)
            {   // achou tudo!
                saida = malloc(comprimento + 1);
                memcpy(saida, alvo, comprimento);
                *(saida + comprimento) = 0;
                return saida;
            };  // if()
            origem += 1;
            break;
        default:
            break;

        }
    };
    // se chegou aqui nao achou nada
    return NULL;
};
```

A lógica é simples: trata-se de um *FSA*, uma máquina de estados porque fica mais fácil de escrever. A ideia é simples: busca a o prefixo, calcula o deslocamento, verifica se tem o conteúdo pedido, aloca a memória, copia os dados e finaliza a string.

Eis a saída de um programa de teste, com uma função `teste()` para mostrar os parâmetros

```
   
        Filtro: Buscando 2 bytes
                0 bytes depois de
                '73' em
                'HS73NSS9374dados:HS73NSS9374N7ALW823'

filtro() retornou 'NS' [2]

        Filtro: Buscando 2 bytes
                0 bytes depois de
                '8' em
                'HS73NSS9374dados:HS73NSS9374N7ALW823'

filtro() retornou '23' [2]

        Filtro: Buscando 3 bytes
                0 bytes depois de
                '8' em
                'HS73NSS9374dados:HS73NSS9374N7ALW823'

filtro() nao encontrou resultado

        Filtro: Buscando 1 bytes
                0 bytes depois de
                '2' em
                'HS73NSS9374dados:HS73NSS9374N7ALW823'

filtro() retornou '3' [1]

        Filtro: Buscando 5 bytes
                2 bytes depois de
                ':' em
                'HS73NSS9374dados:HS73NSS9374N7ALW823'

filtro() retornou '73NSS' [5]

        Filtro: Buscando 19 bytes
                0 bytes depois de
                'dados:' em
                'HS73NSS9374dados:HS73NSS9374N7ALW823'

filtro() retornou 'HS73NSS9374N7ALW823' [19]
```

Entenda que o deslocamento pode ser zero como no caso de seu exemplo. E o valor entre [ ] no exemplo é o comprimento da string retornada

Não quero entrar em discussões religiosas aqui. Compilei só com o CL 19.27 da Microsoft.

### Eis o programa todo

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* filtro19(
    const char*, const char*,
    const size_t, const size_t
);  // o filtro
void    teste(const char*, const char*,
    const size_t, const size_t); // o teste

int     main(void)
{
    teste("HS73NSS9374dados:HS73NSS9374N7ALW823",
        "73", 0, 2);

    teste("HS73NSS9374dados:HS73NSS9374N7ALW823",
        "8", 0, 2);

    teste("HS73NSS9374dados:HS73NSS9374N7ALW823",
        "8", 0, 3);

    teste("HS73NSS9374dados:HS73NSS9374N7ALW823",
        "2", 0, 1);

    teste("HS73NSS9374dados:HS73NSS9374N7ALW823",
        ":", 2, 5);

    teste("HS73NSS9374dados:HS73NSS9374N7ALW823",
        "dados:", 0, 19);

    return 0;
};  // main()

char* filtro19(
    const char*     origem,
    const char*     prefixo,
    const size_t    deslocamento,
    const size_t    comprimento)
{
    size_t    ixIn = 0;
    size_t    ix = 0; // para o deslocamento
    char        st = 0;
    const char* alvo = prefixo;
    char* saida = NULL;
    // vai ate o fim da string de origem
    while (*origem != 0)
    {
        switch (st)
        {

        case 0: // buscando inicio do prefixo
            if (*origem != *prefixo)
            {   // ainda nada
                origem += 1;
                break;
            };  // if()
            origem += 1;
            prefixo += 1;
            st = 1;
            break;

        case 1: // buscando prefixo na string
            if (*prefixo == 0)
            {   // fim do prefixo
                st = 2;
                break;
            };  // if()
            if (*prefixo != *origem)
            {
                st = 0;
                prefixo = alvo; // reinicia prefixo
                break;
            };
            // igual por enquanto
            ixIn += 1; // precisa do tamanho
            origem += 1;
            prefixo += 1;
            break;
    

        case 2: // andando no intervalo
            if (ix == deslocamento)
            {
                st = 3;
                ix = 0; // agora vai contar a saida
                alvo = origem; // aqui comeca o alvo
                break;
            };
            ix += 1; // anda uma casa
            origem += 1;
            break;

        case 3: // agora aponta para a saida e conta
                // os bytes pedidos
            if (*origem == 0)
            {   // acabou antes: nao tem bytes suficientes
                // depois do prefixo e eventual deslocamento
                return NULL;
            };
            ix += 1;
            if (ix == comprimento)
            {   // achou tudo!
                saida = malloc(comprimento + 1);
                memcpy(saida, alvo, comprimento);
                *(saida + comprimento) = 0;
                return saida;
            };  // if()
            origem += 1;
            break;
        default:
            break;

        }
    };
    // se chegou aqui nao achou nada
    return NULL;
};

void        teste(
    const char* origem,
    const char* prefixo,
    const size_t deslocamento,
    const size_t comprimento
)
{
    printf(
        "\n\tFiltro:\tBuscando %zd bytes\n\t\t%zd bytes depois de "
        "\n\t\t'%s' em\n\t\t'%s'\n",
        comprimento, deslocamento, prefixo, origem);
    char* valor = filtro19(origem, prefixo, deslocamento, comprimento);
    if (valor != NULL)
        printf("\nfiltro() retornou '%s' [%zd]\n", valor, strlen(valor));
    else
        printf("\nfiltro() nao encontrou resultado\n");
};  // teste()

// https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/470035/
// retonar-parte-de-uma-string-no-return-da-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o
```